# Plant growing in rock bed

Tags: identification

What is this plant?  Growing well in rock bed with small yellow flowers. The area is Richmond Virginia - in sunny location with good rainfall and temps recently 80 to 92F. [image]

Comment: A decorative wildflower/weed in the pea family?

Comment: @YosefBaskin, why not describe why you think so and make it an answer

Comment: What geographic region?  What climate?  Help us help you!

Comment: Area is Richmond Virginia - in sunny location with good rainfall and temps recently 80 to 92

Comment: I thought it was a clover family plant from leaf pattern but this plant is headed for 4' to '5 in height and flowers are small and yellow - also, leaves fold slightly before dawn

Comment: Thanks for input. I believe it is a peanut plant - except this plant is close to 4 feet tall and has a 3 foot width - seems large for a peanut plant. It does have lots of small yellow flowers.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a [peanut](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.F84iOydZUHfA8feRHxdpRgHaFK%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=26cb60f7d096102cf9ace4daae6039d1f4a360fd0bf9b2569dd2981da60ee2e0&ipo=images). Note the [leaf shape](https://md.gsstatic.es/sfAttachPlugin/48563.jpg) and position and shape of of the flowers.